# What kind of web application should I use to make a private information tool?

Tags: web-apps, project-management

I am trying to find a tool where me and my co-workers can have an structure like this:

```
(Web app)
    - State Foo
        - Business A
            - Project 1
            - Project 2
            - Project 3
        - Business B
            - Project 4
            - Project 5
    - State Bar
        - Business D
            - Project 6
            - Project 7
```

That we can use to keep track of the projects we are working on; where every 'Project' is just a place to post the progress of said project with text, styles, images, attachments, etc., and is only accessible to a certain 'Editor' and a certain 'Viewer' (with the corresponding permissions). It also must be private, so only someone with an account can access the content, a certain 'viewer' must only be able to see projects he's allowed to and all the users can only be created by a site admin.

The only thing that came close to it was using a forum app (phpBB); it has an structure very similar to what we need and has most of the features we expect, but it lacks the option to create users manually.

Is there another app that can fit (or at least come close) to our needs?

Comment: I don't use PHPBB, but it seems you can create users manually with it and the right extensions: https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=2118898

Comment: Looks like a wiki would do, even if it might require a bit of discipline to enforce the project < business < state structure. What would you miss in a wiki?

Comment: I think the main issue in a Wiki would be that you can't restrict access to a 'viewer' to only a certain project, am I wrong? Also, I have to do more research into PHPBB.

Comment: I like DokuWiki https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki, which has a plug-in for user management, including access rights (for both individual users and groups) https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:usermanager

Comment: Compare Wikis for desired features at http://www.wikimatrix.org/  Use the choice wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not quite sure I understand your requirements, have you looked at popular web-app [Trello](http://trello.com/)?

The hierarchical levels of organization in Trello are:

- Organization (basically the whole project)
- Board (basically a screen, a view; an organization can have several boards)
- Lists (a vertical list of cards, a board can have several lists)
- Cards (a small item with a title; it can be opened and contain text, pictures, comments etc.)
- Tasks (a task can be checked off or not; a card can contain one ore more task lists)

You can make users members of organisations or boards (controlling access).
Every card can be assigned to one ore more users.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, I'll look a little more into it in a moment, thanks! By the way, is there a way I can, say, *install* it on my own hosting?

Comment: No, Trello is a hosted service.